# Avoid "Nullable object must have a value." in Linq-To-Sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a method query like this:

```
public IList<BusinessObject> GetBusinessObject(Guid? filterId)
{
    using (var db = new L2SDataContext())
    {
        var result = from bo in db.BusinessObjects
                     where (filterId.HasValue)
                               ? bo.Filter == filterId.value
                               : true
                     orderby bo.Name
                     select SqlModelConverters.ConvertBusinessObject(bo);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

At runtime, this throws a `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

Looking at the Debugger, the problem is my Where Clause: Linq To SQL tries to convert the entire thing to SQL, so even if filterId is NULL, it will still try to access filterId.value.

I thought/hoped the C# compiler/CLR would evaluate that where clause as a code block and only send one of the two branches to Linq To SQL, but that's not how it works.

My refactored version works, but is not very elegant:

```
public IList<BusinessObject> GetBusinessObject(Guid? filterId)
{
    using (var db = new L2SDataContext())
    {
        var temp = from bo in db.BusinessObjects select bo;
        if(filterId.HasValue) temp = temp.Where(t => t.Filter == filterId.Value);
        var result = from t in temp
                     orderby t.Name
                     select SqlModelConverters.ConvertBusinessObject(bo);
        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

I know that Lazy-Evaluation will make sure that only one query is really sent, but having that temp object in there isn't that great really.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Did you try:

```
where filterId == null || t.Filter == filterId
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works perfectly! It saves me from using the slightly unreadable tertiary operator, and it solves the actual Exception which is caused by unnecessarily accessing filterId.Value instead of just filterId.

Answer (score 1):

Your fix is exactly correct.  You are effectively trying to build up a query dynamically, based on your function input.  It's a good idea to omit the where clause instead of supplying `WHERE TRUE` anyway.  If I were writing this query, I would go with your fixed version myself.

It's not as pretty as using the language keywords, but it's still the right way to approach the query in my opinion.